# Get the rotation of an object in the game engine

Tags: python, game-engine

How would I get an object's rotation and set that as another's velocity? Like if I had Object `A`, that has the rotation data, and Object `B`, the object to be moved. How would I get that working in python?

Because of some confusion, here's some of the code:

```
Gun = bpy.data.objects["Gun"]
rotationOfGun = Gun.globalOrientation
```

Comment: So you want to get an object's rotation vector and use that to set another object's velocity?

Comment: That's exactly what I need to do.

Comment: I assume that you're using a rigidbody?

Comment: no, just a Dynamic

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The method for accessing an object's rotation varies depending upon which rendering engine you are using.

In either Blender-Internal or Cycles, you can access an object's rotation by using the Python reference `bpy.context.object.rotation_euler` or just `object.rotation_euler`. In your script, just call that reference and set your other object's velocity based on that.

In the Blender Game Engine, you need to instead use `object.worldOrientation.to_euler()` to retrieve the object's rotation. For example:

```
from bge import logic
cont = logic.getCurrentController()
obj = cont.owner
rotation = obj.worldOrientation.to_euler()
print (rotation.z)
```

Comment: It says this when I try to run it: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<blender_console>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'bpy_prop_collection' object is not callable`

Comment: Did you type ...euler or ...euler() ?

Comment: Wait... >_< I forgot to `import bpy`. But it still fails. (I'm blender 2.66)

Comment: Try the () tip above. That's what the error sounds like. The only other thing I can think of is that you might not be naming the object right. With the format I gave you, the name should be something like cylinder.001, but if you already have the object as a Python variable, it should be just object_name.rotation_euler

Comment: It doesn't work. :(

Comment: This is game-engine you should not use bpy!

Comment: @V360 I caught my mistake. I had assumed you were using Cycles, but the commands are different in the Game Engine. Try using obj.worldOrientation and let me know if that works.

Comment: @Gwenn :( It doesn't work still.

Comment: It says `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<blender_console>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'Object' object has no attribute 'globalOrientation'`

Comment: @V360 Check the code snippet I added in. It works for me in Blender 2.66a.